# System.AccessViolationException Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

Hi im working on a program that uses an array of linked lists but im having trouble running it.  I keep getting this error and I cannot find a way to fix it.  Im only going to include parts of the code that way everything isnt too cluttered.  The error message is saying that lines 112 in NodeADT.h, line 141 in MultiListADT.h and line 21 in main.cpp are the ones throwing the error.  Ill highlight those lines to make it easier.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MultiListADT.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main(void)
{
MultiListADT<string,100> myList;
string item;
ifstream data;
string input;
int x=0;

data.open("input.txt");

while (!data.eof())
{
    getline(data,input);
    myList.AddToFront(input);        //This is line 21
}

cout << myList << endl;

system("pause");
}
```

MultiListADT.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "NodeADT.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <class TYPE,int threads>
class MultiListADT
{
public:
/** Constructor **/
MultiListADT();

/** Destructor **/
~MultiListADT();

/** Declare accessors (observers) **/
void ResetListForward(int=0);
void ResetListBackward(int=0);
bool IsEmpty(int=0);
int LengthIs(int=0);
bool Search(string, bool=true,int=0);
void GetNextItem(TYPE &,int i=0);
void GetPreviousItem(TYPE &,int=0);
int GetInfo(int=0);
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, MultiListADT<TYPE, 100>&);

/** Declare mutators (transformers) **/
void MakeEmpty();
void AddToFront(TYPE);
void AddToRear(TYPE);
void InsertInOrder(TYPE);
void Delete(TYPE);
void Sort();

private:
NodeADT<TYPE,threads>* head[threads];
NodeADT<TYPE,threads>* tail[threads];
int length;
string indices[threads];
NodeADT<TYPE,threads>* currentNode[threads];
};

template <class TYPE,int threads>
MultiListADT<TYPE,threads>::MultiListADT()
{
head[threads] = new NodeADT<string,threads>(); 
tail[threads] = new NodeADT<string,threads>();
head[threads]->setNext(tail[threads]);
tail[threads]->setPrevious(head[threads]);
length = 0;
}

template <class TYPE,int threads>
void MultiListADT<TYPE,threads>::AddToFront(TYPE item)
{
head[0]->AddToFront(item);        //This is line 141

length++;
}
```

NoteADT.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int null = 0;

template<class TYPE, int threads>
class MultiListADT;

template <class TYPE, int threads>
class NodeADT
{
public:
NodeADT();
NodeADT(TYPE);
~NodeADT();
TYPE getInfo();
NodeADT<TYPE, threads>* getPrevious(int=0);
NodeADT<TYPE, threads>* getNext(int=0);
void setNext(NodeADT<TYPE, threads>*,int=0);
void setPrevious(NodeADT<TYPE, threads>*,int=0);
bool Search(TYPE, bool=true,int=0);
void AddToFront(TYPE item);
void AddToRear(TYPE item);
void InsertInOrder(TYPE);
bool Delete(TYPE);
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, MultiListADT<TYPE, threads>&);
private:
TYPE info;
NodeADT<TYPE, threads>* prev[threads];
NodeADT<TYPE, threads>* next[threads];
};

template <class TYPE,int threads>
NodeADT<TYPE,threads>::NodeADT()
{
prev[threads] = null;
next[threads] = null;
}

template <class TYPE,int threads>
NodeADT<TYPE,threads>::NodeADT(TYPE item)
{
info = item;
prev = null;
next = null;
}

template <class TYPE,int threads>
void NodeADT<TYPE,threads>::AddToFront(TYPE item)
{
NodeADT<TYPE,threads> *temp = new NodeADT<TYPE,threads>;
temp->info = item;  
temp->prev[0] = this;
temp->next[0] = next[0];
next[0]->prev[0] = temp;        //This is line 112
next[0] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but `eof` doesn't work (like that).

Comment: Could you explain how eof doesnt work in this case because it has been for me.

Comment: @Soul3lade: eof() will not be set until getline tries to read at the end of the file. So what you are doing is always reading an empty `input` value at the end. You should probably be doing while( getline( ...

Answer (score 0):

What do *YOU* think the error means?

On line 112, where do the values for next, prev and temp come from and what are they set to when it crashes? Knowing the values, why do you think it crashed?

Also in one of your NodeADT constructors you assign null to the last element of the array. Or so it appears.

Question: What happens when you assign a value to the element numbered 100 in an array of 100 elements, when element counting starts at 0?

Comment: Im guessing im trying to access memory that i cannot while the program is running.  Temp->info is the item that is sent in while Temp->prev would be the same address while temp->next is set to the next address in the list.  prev and next never get set because thats where the program crashes.  To your question you would be assigning a value out of the bounds of the array which would cause an error.

Comment: @Soul3lade: that is what you *think* the addresses are set to. however, this is not the case. Once you discover what happened there, you will be a better programmer, so I'm leaving it to you to figure it out.

Comment: Alright I completely understand my having to learn what is going on exactly however care to offer any hints.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer, which Zan Lynx has implied, is that you are using `threads` as an index into your arrays in the constructor of `MultiListADT`. In `AddToFront` you use 0 as the index, but that element in the array has never been initialised.

Comment: Alright im confused now, I thought threads was just an int allowing me to declare how big the array of lets say next[] was going to be. So by using next[0] i was just using the first list of the array.

Comment: That is all correct (threads is an int and next[0] is the first element in the array) but in your constructor you are not assigning a value to next[0]. You _are_ assigning a value to next[100], which is outside the bounds of the array, but it looks like you probably want to assign the value to next[0]. I'll assume you are going to add more code to do something with the other 99 lists later :)

Comment: Alright so change 
    next[threads] = null; 
to
     next[0] = null;

Comment: Well there are a number of places where you are using _something_ [threads] and they should probably all be changed. Again, I  assume you have some reason for having arrays of lists so presumably you'll ultimately be using next[_something_] rather than hard coding a single index that never changes at run time.

Comment: Yeah the reason for the array is that something[0] will be the entire list that is read in while something[1-99] will be more lists that have common parts of the main list tied together so say something[1] would be strings that contain "hello" etc.  However i changed the constructors to instead have [threads] to have [0] although im still receiving the same error so either I missed something or there is more to it.

Comment: never heard of a skip list care to explain.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there is more than one error here. I think your best bet is probably to step through in the debugger and try to understand what is going wrong that way.